# how to use database from visual studio code (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

i can't use Syetem.Data.SqlClient.

this is my code

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient; // <== error

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

i make this project from console, and input 'dotnet new' and restore.

what shold i do?

Comment: This may be of use to you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545346/asp-net-core-could-not-load-system-data-sqlclient

Comment: What's the error say?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added "System.Data.dll" to your project reference?

Answer (score 0):

Add reference for SQL server data from project references. If there is not such option then run the Setup of visual studio select option *Modify* and then select SQL data option and run the setup.